Springboot Modelmapper mapping error when occurs mapping
**This is my entitity class **
@Entity
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String idNumber;
    private UserRole userRole;
}

This is my requestDto class
@Data
public class SignupRequest {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String idNumber;
}


Mapping logic
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<StandardResponse> createUserAccount(SignupRequest signupRequest) {
        try {
            if (!userRepository.existsByEmail(signupRequest.getEmail())){
                System.out.println(signupRequest);
                User user = modelMapper.map(signupRequest,User.class);
                user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(signupRequest.getPassword()));
                user.setUserRole(UserRole.EMPLOYEE);
                userRepository.save(user);
                return new ResponseEntity<StandardResponse>(new StandardResponse(201,"User account added"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<StandardResponse>(new StandardResponse(400,"This user account already added"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<StandardResponse>(new StandardResponse(400,"Error occurred while adding new user"+e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }


If i enter some string with number like "455gb" in idNumber then below error is shown but if i enter only number it works normally.
error output
"Error occurred while adding new userModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter@d35d185 failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Long.\n\n1 error"
How to fix this error and what are the bug in my code

You defined id as Long, so entering an alphanumeric should fail.  You need to check for this condition.
